# Is this sentence in past tense or not?

Tags: past-simple

Is this in past simple or not? I am confused that even though it is in past, it express thought about the present.

> I had no idea you loved me.

Comment: There are two tensed clauses in this sentence (_I had no idea_ and _you loved me_). Both of these clauses are in past tense (_had_ is past tense, and _loved_ is past tense). The sentence itself has no tense because it's a complex sentence, and tenses in the clauses of complex sentences are independent of one another. It's just a coincidence that both clauses are the same tense in this example.

Comment: "The sentence itself has no tense because it's a complex sentence and tenses in complex sentences are independent;" If you mean complex sentence in the usual linguistic sense (possessing a dependent clause), I cannot agree. The tense of the independent clause is the tense of the sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Your comment is fascinating. I wish you'd provide an aswer to that effect. I can't recall ever seeing a sentence parsed as having _no tense!_ My impulse is to agree with eques here, but often in the past when my first reaction to one of your analyses was "oh, that can't be right," my reaction has turned out to be wrong.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Consider the sentence "I was happy then and I am happy now." What is its tense--present or past?

Comment: @StoneyB Well, that's a model of conciseness. Still, it rankles somehow to think of a sentence as having _no tense._ It's like imagining a shirt with no color. How about this: what tense would a prescriptivist ascribe to _I was happy then and I am happy now._? Or would she be reduced to a paroxysm of stammering and run screaming into the wilderness?

Comment: Tense applies to verbs, which always occur in clauses. Hence tense applies only to clauses, not to sentences per se. A simple sentence has only one clause, so saying that such a sentence is in the past tense is harmless -- unless one assumes, incorrectly, that 'having a tense' is meaningful with  **all** sentences, just because it makes sense with simple sentences.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have no idea what traditionalists say now. When I was younger so much younger than today my teachers would say "Don't be clever, Thomas." . . . What color is a plaid shirt?

Comment: @JohnLawler Of course this all is clear and obvious now that I've had an espresso and read what you (& young Tom) write. Only a verb must have tense. DOH! It's a shame that an inaccurate (if well-reasoned) answer has now been accepted by the OP.

Comment: Overgeneralizations like that are typical of "traditional" grammar rules. Then the students find the exceptions to the traditional rules and don't know what to believe. That's why I have no use for "traditional grammar"; it's a cheat.

Comment: @StoneyB For completeness here, in response to _What color is a plaid shirt?_ I would now say: _"The shirt is made of fabric woven of red, green, and black threads; the shirt **itself** has no color to call its own."_ (For which cheek I would have been assigned two hours extra study hall...)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Just to make sure you don't get too confident, I would have you know that it's not so simple. Dr. Lawler, a deeply learned professional, appears to hold with the Comrie sect (perhaps only in a Laodicean degree) that *tense* is "grammaticalized location in time"--in English, therefore, an attribute of the verb. I, on the other hand, though merely a half-educated amateur, hold that *tense* is an attribute of utterances; *tense* may (or may not) grammatically elicit specific verb forms, but those forms do not necessarily express *tense*.

Comment: @StoneyB Fear not. "Confidence" in this context is not, I think, a virtue, and I have few of those in any case. In a discipline that can't even agree on the order of the letters **A, M,** and **T,** or even whether **T** belongs in the series, I have nothing on which to base even an opinion on such things. I quoted Homer Simpson quite consciously. It's enough to me if a new student of English can make sense of a given usage suffiecient to permit the later employment of that usage without our help, and the terms used to elicit that understanding are not as important as the understanding.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've been reading what you write for decades (as a USENET lurker) and you've made many things seem obvious that at first were murky to me only because of the confusion introduced by those generalizations you properly decry. So in principle I agree. What I don't see is how to help a NNS to grasp English without having crutches like _tense_ at hand: familiar concepts they can use to learn the new language by referring to their own. Without them it seems as if we're handing the students a basket full of snakes and asking them to invent herpetology for themselves.

Comment: No problem, StoneyB; I know you mean semantic TAM. But I still use _tense_ in its morphological sense; it's syntactic, not semantic, in English. Semantics is a whole nother kettle of fish. And @P.E.Dant, thanks for the kind words. My tentative answer to your question is to start [from logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), which they are likely to enjoy, since it's math-like but doesn't require arithmetic, and then [proceed to sentences](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) as what comes out when we mean certain logical (i.e, semantic) constructions.

Comment: Calling the sentence tenseless is little more than intellectual jump-roping. If the two clauses were independent, then I might agree that the overall sentence has an indeterminate or mixed tense as in the sentence "It was raining but it now is sunny". In this case, the second clause is subordinate to the primary clause. Furthermore, since tense is a grammatical expression of time, we can rule out non-past since all verbs in the sentence are past tense verbs (especially given they are all indicative)

Comment: @P.E.Dant So what we should do instead is hand the students a basketful of snakes and tell them it's a basketful of rope, useful for tying things together?

Comment: @StoneyB Oh dear. I was afraid of this. I didn't consider the metaphor before invoking it. If vexillology intrudes we veer toward consideration of autonomously-created knots and other disturbing images. It might indeed be possible as Mr Lawler says to start with logic and progress to sentences, but since the NNSs under consideration were taught that their first language is constructed of things like tenses and parts of speech, their learning English without those things requires them to first forget everything they learned about their own! This seems to increase their burden unfairly.

Comment: @StoneyB Aren't we talking about pedagogy now? I thought that was a red word hereabouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be past simple. The sentence is made up of two clauses, one of which is subordinate.

The two clauses are:

> 1. I had no idea
> 2. (that) you loved me

that as a conjunction can be omitted in many cases.

*had* is the past simple of have. Likewise *loved* is the past simple of love.

The sentence is describing a past state of thought, which was changed in the present. That is, it indicates the lack of knowledge in the past about the other person's love.

It is roughly equivalent to:

> I didn't know (that) you loved me.

Comment: Just to be clear, we don't know when the action in the sentence is taking place -- see John Lawler's comment on the question, that this sentence really has "no tense" because there's nothing to indicate when the action happens. Otherwise you're correct that "had" indicates a past condition (relative to the speaker's "now") that has been changed.

Comment: Per OED, the elided _that_ here seems less a conjunction than a pronoun introducing the clause _(that) you loved me,_ cf. _I am monarch of all I survey._ (Cowper.)

Comment: "Conjunction" is better than "pronoun" for it, but now it's usually called a "complementis/zer".

Comment: I meant to write _relative_ pronoun above (per OED) which might have made more sense. I can't argue that this is the relative _that_ (and certainly not in 650 characters!) so I agree that _complementiser_ is a better label as I've seen it defined. It's not important to the answer, at least.

Comment: @Andrew. See my response to JohnLawler's original comment. The question is about tense which is related to time, but the fact that there is no mention of when is irrelevant. It is a past tense verb and furthermore you can't in English mix tenses and temporal adverbial phrases entirely freely; e.g. something like "Tomorrow, I had no idea you loved me" is nonsense. The statement has two clauses the second of which is subordinate so the independent clauses tense is the overall tense, which is past.

Comment: @eques Yes, I agree.  However it would be weird, but still fine to say, "Sometime in the future, I will tell you that I had no idea that you loved me."  This is in response to the specific question asked -- the relative time the sentence is spoken is unknown, although without any additional context I would assume it's "now".

Comment: @Andrew but that sentence shows the same principle as the OP's but with one additional layer. It's a future tense statement with an embedded past tense sentence.